# website name on facebook appears as index

Tags: html, facebook, title, meta

my website:
www.thebigbeatsinc.com

When I post it to facebook, it says index.hmtl and not TheBigBeatsInc.com: Recording Studio, Computer and Media Solutions

here is my meta - I gave the site a title and it still will not display. Please help!

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Big Beats Inc. Recording Studios"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.TheBigBeatsInc.com/"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="The Big Beats Inc. is a world class, legendary, and state of the art vintage recording studio operated by PAUL LIVORSI. It is located in the scenic setting of the Hudson River Valley in Beacon, NY; not far from the legendary music cultural center of Woodstock, NY."/>
```

Comment: Why don't you create a Facebook app? It would also enable the option to have custom "via _______" along with the one you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the title tag is set in the head section of your webpage.

Ex:

```
<head>
  <title>The Big Beats Inc. Recording Studios</title>
</head>
```

Source: http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/titles/